# How to run react-js project? Error appears while run this project

Tags: reactjs

I can't run react-js app on next day of creation. I don't know how it is appear. When I create project using npx create-react-app app-name, it's working on that same day but whenever I open and start that project on very nect day, It doesn't work and this error appears which I cannot solve, and can't find any solution over anywhere. Please take a look in image and suggest any solution for this error.
[image]

Comment: `npx i create-react-app app-name ` or `npx create-react-app app-name `?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. `npx create-react-app app-name`

Comment: is it throwing the same error while using `npx create-react-app app-name `?

Comment: Yes, everyytime when using on very next day of creation.

Comment: @JohnOcean Have you tried to nuke the entire `node_modules/` directory and `package-lock.json` file, then run `npm i` and finally `npm start`?

Comment: @TaiweiTuan Yes, I tried it but it also not working.